# Creating font using constraints

Tags: software-recommendation, font-design, design-process

I want to create my own font by using constraints. I want to define the size of angles, how long lines are, distance between points and so on. For example the sketch editor of FreeCAD offers this functionality but only for constructing parts in 3D and not fonts. I have tried a lot font creation tools like fontforge but creating a font feels more like drawing something with paint.

Which font creation tools offer this functionality?

Comment: None that i know of. But there is really no reason why you could not import this info from elsewhere.

Comment: This is actually a pretty deep artificial intelligence problem that I don't think has really been "cracked" yet. (Google "Godel escher bach gridfont" ; "font neural net" etc)

Answer (score 1):

I have to this day not seen a constraints based application in a graphics design context *. This includes a font editor. To my knowledge this does not exist.

But please note: The font editor does not have to be the source of your glyphs. Think of something like fontforge as a compiler for your font. All you need to do is export the font to a eps file with a suitable template name and fontforge will auto associate it with a glyph in your font. This allows you to use whatever app you like for the task. I have personally used Creo and Mathematica** for this in the past, so I dont really see why you could not use free cad for it. Just the toolset in the middle may need to be built.

* There may be a reason for this. The solvers are O(N^2) up untill very rcently.

** And notepad